# how can i use two onChange function in the same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use to `onChange` functions in the same component but it is not allowed.

I have tried to mix them but I couldn't since one of them is `useState` and the other one is a const function

Here is my code

```
const signup = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handlePasswordChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

  return(
    <Input
      //    type="password"
      id="passwordInput"
      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      placeholder="Yaziniz"
      type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
      onChange={handlePasswordChange("password")}
      value={values.password}
    />
```

How can I use both of these two `onChange` handlers in the same component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call both of them in onChange handler

```js
onChange={(e) => {
  setPassword(e.target.value);
  handlePasswordChange("password")(e);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is use these function to one onChange.

```
<Input 
  onChange={(e) => { 
    setPassword(e.target.value)
    handleChangePassword("password")
    ...otherFunctions
  }
/>
```

Comment: it doesn't work because handleChangePassword() is a higher-order function

Comment: it doesnt work, still refusing to type in password input field

Comment: @Javokhir It's a curried function, not a higher order function. 

Comment: Sr my bad. Just add (e) behind handleChangePassword("password")(e). It's done.

Answer (score -1):

just add && operator to next function

```
onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value) && yourFunction}
```

Comment: it is still refusing to type in the password input :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).